# Creating a connection between EmguCV and my projected gameboard

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, emgucv, aforge

I am trying to create an interactive boardgame in Unity, using hand gestures to activate mechanics. The game will be projected on a table with a camera attached next to it, which will be used to capture motion.

The game consists of two grids, one 30x30 hidden tile grid, with a map grid on top of it.

**My question is then:** What is the smartest way to go around synchronizing the camera with the hidden tile grid, so I can see if a detected BLOB from my EmguCV is on top of set tile?

**I've considered:**

- Creating another tilemap for the camera, and check if the tile number
  in both   tilemaps are equal to eachother.
- Check if tile center position is close to blob center position, using
  Unitys method Vector2.Distance